# What is the difference between code in javascript onchange and the same code in a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline

I am a novice at Javascript.  But I have to use it in one of my projects.

I have a tabbed control that sets the value of a hidden control from various events on the page (tab clicks and dropdowns).  The hidden control is fed a JSON string, and a button is clicked that executes some server side code and populates data in the page controls.

When I run this code directly in the onchange event of the hidden input, the behavior is different than when I pull out the Javascript and put it in a function.

I need to pull it out so I can do a couple of other minor things in the function that seem to complex for the inline code in the onchagne event.

Here is the code that functions properly.

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState" 
onchange="$('#<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>').val(this.value); 
document.getElementById('<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>').click();" />
```

COMPARED TO THIS CODE.  Which has a different affect.

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState" onchange="compareUnitValues(this.value)" />


    <script type ="text/javascript">
        function compareUnitValues(args) {
            $('#<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>').val(args);               
            document.getElementById('<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.
Tom

Comment: What *is* the different effect?

Comment: The button that is clicked is part of a webpart containing a reportviewer control.  The "inline" javascript ( is that how I should refer to it?), causes the reportviewer to be refreshed with the data from the server properly in any tab clicked.  There are multiple tabs with a webpart/reportviewer embedded in each.  With the function call, only one of the webpart/reportviewers will refresh, the others don't refresh.  But I watch the exact same code execute on the server on the postback.  Strange.

Comment: I don't see any buttons in your code

Comment: clicking it programmatically here.  document.getElementById('<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>').click()  and thanks for responding.  I appreciate that you took the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, let's break it by parts and I'm going to assume that `ASP_SSRS` is inside a control, that is why you have a bit more of an overhead.

when you call directly:

```
$('#<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>').val(this.value); 
document.getElementById('<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>').click();
```

you have in that like the correct *client* elements... as you are putting your method away from that line, you loose them completely, in other words, by the time the ASP.NET renders your new method, it does not know the `ASP_SSRS` and/or `btnSendHiddenField`.

The only way, is to pass these into the method it self.

if you write your method signature as:

```
function compareUnitValues(elmt, value1, value2)
```

you can then, inside, request their properties and assign any value you want, so let's wrap it up:

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState" 
       onchange="compareUnitValues(this.id, '<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>', '<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>');" />
```

this way, your passing the input `<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState` as `this` -> `this` is the element that is associate where the method is fired, in this case, you're calling the method on `<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState` element.

in our case, **it's much easier by just passing the ID as well**, you will see when we write the javascript method!

```
<input type="hidden" id="<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState" 
       onchange="compareValues('<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>_tracDatState', '<%= ASP_SSRS.ClientID %>', '<%= btnSendHiddenField.ClientID %>');" />
```

you are also passing the correct elements `id` 's for the elements you want to manipulate, as by that line the ASP.NET Render Engine knows exactly hat is `ASP_SSRS` and `btnSendHiddenField`.

your method call, after rendered, will look something like:

```
onchange="compareValues('Ctrl001_ASP_SSRS_tracDatState', 'Ctrl001_ASP_SSRS', 'Ctrl001_btnSendHiddenField');"
```

and witch such values, you can do plenty now:

```
function compareUnitValues(elemt, value1, value2) {

     var state   = $("#" + elemt),
         ssrs    = $("#" + value1),
         btnSend = $("#" + value2);

     // assign state value to ssrs
     ssrs.val(state.val());

     // trigger the send button
     btnSend.trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir!  That makes sense.  I am shocked at how quickly and concisely you answered my question.  I really really appreciate the help.  I am going to put this in play and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: copy/paste your call, from the browser (not code) - so, after been rendered. The one inside the `onchange` so I can see what are you passing.

Comment: I deleted my other comments.  I mistakenly commented out the jquery script.  doh!  I made some minor edits to your code in case someone else wants to use it.  It works perfectly.  Thanks again, this was very helpful for a project with tight deadlines.